# How to add code sections that would be visible in Pycharm structure window

Tags: python, pycharm, structure

I'd like to group functions, so it would be easier to navigate them in Pycharm structure window.

I tried using `#region ... #endregion` , but it's not visible in structure window. It only allows to collapse a piece of code.

I also looked for some addons or tools to do it, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Setting bookmarks and using the bookmark tab does exactly what you want.

Comment: `#regions` / `#endregion` are here to define code-structures (as the name 'region' says),
therefore, to replace regions by Bookmarks is a bad coder suggestion ;-)

The first time `#region` and `#endregion` were used was in November 2005 by Visual Studio 2005, and it's a shame that JetBrains still doesn't support it after almost two decades(!).